# SQL Select to return 2 rows one for each column in table

Tags: mysql, select

Please excuse my ability to formulate a suitable title.

I have a table with the columns:

```
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name  | char(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| pri   | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sec   | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

with data like

```
+--------+------+------+
| name   | pri  | sec  |
+--------+------+------+
| first  |    1 |    2 |
| second |    3 |    4 |
| third  |    5 |    6 |
+--------+------+------+
```

I would like a select that will give the results:

```
+--------+------+
| name   | addr |
+--------+------+
| first  |    1 |
| first  |    2 |
| second |    3 |
| second |    4 |
| third  |    5 |
| third  |    6 |
+--------+------+
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Will you `sec`-`pri` **always** equal 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT name, pri AS addr
FROM Table1
WHERE pri is NOT NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT name, sec AS addr
FROM Table1
WHERE sec is NOT NULL

order by 1,2
```

Comment: I guess it was a pretty easy question. I have not used union but that is the knowledge I was lacking. Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will return the specified resultset:

```
SELECT p.name
     , p.pri AS addr
  FROM mytable p
 UNION ALL 
SELECT s.name
     , s.sec AS addr
  FROM mytable s
 ORDER BY 2 ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you `UNION` the query like below. See a demo here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4338/2

```
select name, pri as addr
from table1

union all

select name, sec as addr
from table1
order by addr
```